# How can I get the foreign-key name of `user` of `users` table using `Shop` model in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, relationship, query-builder

`shops` table

```php
         Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false);
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->float('rating')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('location_id');

            $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> Here is the `shops` table. And it has `user_id` which is foreign key of `users` table.

`users` table

```php
         Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->longText('cartitems')->nullable();
            $table->longText('wishlist')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('discount')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> This is the `users` table

`Shop` model (relatonship)

```php
public function seller()    //user --> seller
{
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

> Here I try to make a relationship between `Shop` and `User`

`DashboardController`

```php
public function shops()
{
    $shops = Shop::all();

    dd($shops->seller()->name);
}
```

> Here I want to get the name of the `seller` of the shop

`What I am getting after run the project`

> BadMethodCallException
> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::seller does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$shops is a collection. It's a collection of instances of Shop Model. And seller is relation of Shop Model.

```
foreach($shops as $shop){
    echo $shop->seller->name;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro.... I got it now..... We need individual item to get the name.

Comment: Yes, and it's better if you eager load the seller relation.   `$shops = Shop::with('seller')->get();`

Comment: thanks bro... Obviously I do.... thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Will you hits me.. what is the advantages of doing so? like Shop::with('seller')

Comment: Read it here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading